# JPAでManyToOneを設定すると自動でセッターが生えているような記述を見るが実際にやるとUnresolved referenceが発生します

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-boot, hibernate

JPAでManyToOneを設定し、親と子を同時に保存する適切な方法を探しています（別々にsaveすることはできました）。

[one to many - Hibernate: OneToMany save children by cascade - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650453/hibernate-onetomany-save-children-by-cascade)
を見ると `parent.setChildren(children);` といようにセッターを使っている例があるのですが、試しに私の環境で試してみると`Unresolved reference`が発生します。
ちなみに私はJavaではなくKotlinを使用しています。

[JPA / Hibernate One to Many Mapping Example with Spring Boot | CalliCoder](https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-mapping-example/)
でも似たような例があるのですが、コメントで、Winnerさんが `comment.setPost(post); //error here` と書いており、私と同じようにセッターの部分でエラーになっているようです。
なぜ、セッターの例がこれほどまでにネットにあるのにエラーになるのでしょうか？

ちなみにKotlinで、Spring BootとHibernateを使っています。

---

公式サンプルpetclinicを見ると、自分でセッター、ゲッター書いてますね。
[spring-petclinic-kotlin/Owner.kt at master · spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-kotlin](https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/owner/Owner.kt)
もしかして、ネットにある例は、自分でセッター、ゲッターくらい書いてねということを何も明記せずに掲載されています...？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> もしかして、ネットにある例は、自分でセッター、ゲッターくらい書いてねということを何も明記せずに掲載されています...？

その通りかと思います。
もう少し親切に、 "getters and setters omitted for brevity" と言うようなコメントが付与されているコードサンプルもしばしば目にします。